# Class for first element in smarty foreach

Tags: smarty

I'm trying to add some smarty to my template , to first element i want to give

```
 <div class="item active">
```

and for next elements

```
 <div class="item">
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
 {foreach $imageCollection as $image key=slider}
      {if $slider < 1} 
             <div class="item active">
                   <img class="img-responsive" src="{$image->getPath('1400x469')}" alt="caption1" />
                   <div class="carousel-caption">
      {else}
             <div class="item">
                   <img class="img-responsive" src="{$image->getPath('1400x469')}" alt="caption1" />
                   <div class="carousel-caption">
      {/if}
 {/foreach}
```

It's doesn't work, all elements are displaying with

```
<div class="item active">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [@first](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.first):

```
{foreach $imageCollection as $image}
  <div class="item {if $image@first}active{/if}">
  ...


{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for getting the index key in Smarty is as following:

```
{foreach from=$imageCollection item=image key=slider}
    // Your code
{/foreach}
```